# How create two dimensional (2D) string array dynamic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If the word is ABC

> ```
> A[0][0]="AA"   A[0][1]="AB"   A[0][2]="AC"
> A[1][0]="BA"   A[1][1]="BB"   A[1][2]="BC"
> A[2][0]="CA"   A[2][1]="CB"   A[2][2]="CC"
> ```

using for, string or array method.

Comment: show us your code and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [..."ABC"];

console.log(
  a.map(l => a.map(c => l + c))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

An odd request. Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const word = "ABC";
const letters = word.split("");
const array = [];
letters.forEach((letter1,index1) => {
  letters.forEach((letter2,index2) => {
     if (!array[index1]) {
        array[index1] = [];
     }
     array[index1][index2] = letter1+letter2;
  });
});
console.log(array);
```

**UPDATE:**

Another version using older Javascript. Also, check out Asaf's solution using a more functional approach below, is very elegant.

```js
var word = "ABC";
var letters = word.split("");
var array = [];
for(var index1 = 0;index1!==letters.length;index1++) {
  for(var index2 = 0;index2!==letters.length;index2++) {
     if (!array[index1]) {
        array[index1] = [];
     }
     array[index1][index2] = letters[index1]+letters[index2];
  }
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: I've added a version without the forEach

Comment: Geogebra say this message: org.mozilla.javascript.Nativearray@5325dfd6

Comment: When this message appears, I must use the alert command to see the information of the array variable, but I must create a variable string (var str_ that processes it to txt so that the alert command understands it. str={{"AA","AB","AC"},{"BA","BB","BC"},{"CA","CB","CC"}}.

Comment: I already managed to do the other part of the code I wanted. Thank you so much! I cann't place here because it exceeds the characters.

Comment: That's good to hear. If you found my help useful then please upvote my answer.